# Replanting a Bougainvillea: Need a Plan

Tags: trees, bougainvillea

So I had a bougainvillea that was over a walkway for decades. I had an HVAC condenser installed next to it and it was fine, then it got used a lot one year and the tree just died. Termites came in and ate the corpse.

I really want to plant in the same place. Here to see what people think about my theory of why the other one died, and also what sized plant I should purchase to put there. I am usually not wanting to get larger plants as the roots are probably impacted, possibly dooming the plant.

[image: sites of the original bushes]

The circles show where the 2 prior plants were then they formed an arch over the walkway. The fence has been replaced. It was completely eaten through by termites. The house is redwood so there was no damage there. Doubt the termites killed the bougainvillea but maybe? They are gone.

So any thoughts on optimal replacement strategy is my question.

Comment: Was the output of the HVAC directed towards the B?  They like sun not cold air vented in their direction.

Comment: It was probably hot air coming from the compressor.

Comment: Can you add a photo or two of the place where the HVAC and the bougainvilla are/were?

Comment: Will add some photos Stephie, thanks for your interest!